# Importing Delimited File to Excel with Macro (.CommandType = 0)

Tags: excel, vba

Lots of similar questions going on but google and stack overflow are not touching the part I think I need. I am trying to import a pipe delimited text file with a macro. When I record macro, this is what I get:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\johnsmith\Desktop\Macro Tinkering\ABC_Financials_ALL(Delimited).txt" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "ABC_Financials_ALL(Delimited)_1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

When I try to run the macro, it fails, and when I debug, it points me in the direction of ".CommandType = 0"

Anyone know if there is a value that will get this macro going? Or are my problems worse than that?

Comment: try removing the `.CommandType = 0` completely and rerun the macro

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735171/how-to-import-csv-data-into-excel-after-selecting-file-from-userform

Comment: A) I did try to just remove it, just moves the error to the next line. B) Youre right, they are very similar questions, but no answer was never given for your link and I cant bump someone elses post.

Comment: It worked for me when I deleted the `.CommandType = 0`. Make sure you `stop` the macro and then restart

Answer (score 1):

Alright.

More confident in just deleting possible trash off Mukul215's suggestion, I kept deleting stuff and retrying.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\johnsmith\Desktop\Macro Tinkering\ABC_Financials_ALL(Delimited).txt" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

And this one does it.