# Importing Delimited File to Excel with Macro; Run-time error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a list of CSV files I want to import into a blank Excel spreadsheet.
I tried to import one file using the code shown below, but I get a run time error:

```
Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error
```

The error is triggered by the following line:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=strConnexn, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

I saw the StackOverflow example at "[Importing Delimited File to Excel with Macro (.CommandType = 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082226/importing-delimited-file-to-excel-with-macro-commandtype-0)"

The line of code where my macro "subImportIntermediaCSVCallLogs_aaa" chokes seems to my ignorant mind be identical to the StackOverflow example; but obviously I am mistaken.

Although I usually can figure out Word's vba, I have no experience coding in Excel vba, and I do not know where to look for an explanation.

Once I get the macro "subImportIntermediaCSVCallLogs_aaa(strCSV_Fullname)" running, my plan is to use the macro "subRunMacroOnSeveralCSV_files()" to import a bunch of CSV files into the same spreadsheet, with each import beginning 4 lines beneath the previous import.
Please let me know if you think that that is unwise.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Sub subImportIntermediaCSVCallLogs_aaa(strCSV_Fullname)
'
    Dim strConnexn As String

    strConnexn = Chr(34) & "TEXT;" & strCSV_Fullname & Chr(34)
    MsgBox strConnexn

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=strConnexn, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True       
        .FieldNames = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A1,1:1048576").Select
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select

    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Select

End Sub ' End of subImportIntermediaCSVCallLogs_aaa(strCSV_Fullname)


Sub subRunMacroOnSeveralCSV_files()
    Dim strCSV_Fullname As String
    strCSV_Fullname = "E:\Intermedia\CallHistory\callhistory01.csv"
    strCSV_Fullname = "E:\Intermedia\CallHistory\callhistory02.csv"
    strCSV_Fullname = "E:\Intermedia\CallHistory\callhistory03.csv"
    subImportIntermediaCSVCallLogs_aaa strCSV_Fullname

End Sub ' End of subRunMacroOnSeveralCSV_files()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this code was produced. When I record a macro and go to Data -> Get & Transform data -> From Text/CSV, the code generated is different from yours. Why don't you simply open the csv rather than adding a query table?

Comment: I have about 16 files to import as data.One of the fields needs to be imported as a date type (year/m/day).  It takes a fair amount of time to do that, and I tend to leave something out or otherwise screw up, when I do it manually for 16 files.  I want to be able to get this info in real time on a frequent basis by just clicking a button.

Comment: This is how you open a csv: `Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\test.csv"`